# Angular Dynamic Sidenav/Router Outlet Potential Bug

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and was attempting to make the Sidenav component be collapsible in "over" mode on viewport sizes less than or equal to 600px and open and in "side" mode in viewport sizes greater than 600px. When the app loads with the viewport greater than 600px, there is a gap between the router-outlet and the mat-sidenav. When you change the viewport size, the content snaps back to full width. When you change out the router-outlet with static content, it loads full-width as well. I wasn't sure if this was something I was doing wrong, or if this is some kind of bug. [Here is a demo on StackBlitz that demonstrates the behavior](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f9scjs).

After initial load:

[image]

After viewport resize:

[image]

So, I guess the question is, am I doing something wrong or is this a bug of some kind?

Comment: Not happening with FF. You might create an issue on gh.

Comment: @RobinDijkhof Huh, didn't think about it being a Chrome issue. Tried it in Safari, same as FF, doesn't happen.

Comment: FYI: The issue can also reproduced with edge.